# What does "display.style" do in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, toggle

I was practising toggle switch function....

**FULL HTML CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
#myDIV {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-top: 20px;
  display="block"

}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click the "Try it" button to toggle between hiding and showing the DIV element:</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<div id="myDIV">
This is my DIV element.
</div>

<p><b>Note:</b> The element will not take up any space when the display property set to "none".</p>

<script>
function myFunction() {

if (myDIV.style.display == "block") {
    myDIV.style.display = "none";
} else {
    myDIV.style.display = "block";
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

In order for the div element to disappear, I have to click it twice (only when the page first loads). I was able to fix it by setting the **CSS display** to `none;` instead of `block;*. What might be causing this?

Also, I've realized that having **===** or **==** or **=** sign after `myDIV.style.display` causes different results. I was wondering why that is?

p.s. The original content I was experimenting is this: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_toggle_hide_show

Comment: `display="block"` is not css syntax, you should use `display : block`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your code,whenever you clicked first- `myIDV.style.display` return an empty string `""`, for this it goes to else block,set inline style to block,but it has already this style.So you don't get any visible effect.After first click-it will goes as you want.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
#myDIV {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-top: 20px;
  display="block"

}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click the "Try it" button to toggle between hiding and showing the DIV element:</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<div id="myDIV">
This is my DIV element.
</div>

<p><b>Note:</b> The element will not take up any space when the display property set to "none".</p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
console.log(myDIV.style.display);
if (myDIV.style.display == "block") {
    myDIV.style.display = "none";
} else {
    myDIV.style.display = "block";
  }
}
</script>

</body>
```

**Here is the solution,what you looking for.**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
#myDIV {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-top: 20px;
  display="block"

}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click the "Try it" button to toggle between hiding and showing the DIV element:</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<div id="myDIV">
This is my DIV element.
</div>

<p><b>Note:</b> The element will not take up any space when the display property set to "none".</p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
 var style = getComputedStyle(myDIV);
if (style.getPropertyValue("display") == 'block') {
     myDIV.style.display = "none";
} else {
    myDIV.style.display = "block";
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
Could you enlighten me on why JS will read "" for the first execution?

Comment: `el.style.display` return `value` if it has any `inline` style value,otherwise it returns empty `""` as a value.

Comment: please give up-vote and if you think this is your answer,please mark it as a answer- it will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction() {
if (window.getComputedStyle(myDIV).display == "block") {
    myDIV.style.display = "none";
} else {
    myDIV.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
#myDIV {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<p>Click the "Try it" button to toggle between hiding and showing the DIV element:</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<div id="myDIV">
This is my DIV element.
</div>

<p><b>Note:</b> The element will not take up any space when the display property set to "none".</p>
```